# Power BI Fixed Decimal has two digits, not four

Tags: powerbi, etl, powerquery

All documentations and tutorials out there mention that transforming a table column to Data Type 'Fixed Decimal' will make it have four digits to the right of the period symbol.

However, when I use this type, it only shows two and the Power Query for that step has:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(myTable,{{"fieldName", Currency.Type}})
```

Was the default behaviour changed or do I need to first set some setting to get four? I tried this with multiple files.

Comment: OK this is a bit embarrassing. Apparently the column in the Transform Data view shows two digits, but the Data view shows four digits. Nothing to see here.